# I need help parallelizing a code with MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i,n,sum=0;
   printf("Input Value of terms : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("\nThe first %d natural numbers are:\n",n);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
     printf("%d ",i);
     sum+=i;
   }
   printf("\nThe Sum of natural numbers upto %d terms : %d \n",n,sum);

}
```

```
Input Value of terms : 7                                                                                      
                                                                                                              
The first 7 natural number is :                                                                               
1 2 3 4 5 6 7                                                                                                 
The Sum of Natural Number upto 7 terms : 28
```

I think I should parallelize the cycle that performs the sum, but in what part would that guideline be placed and how?

It gives me this result but I need to parallelize with mpi

Comment: You should identify a domain to decompose, distribute pieces of work among the ranks and assemble the local results. If you have 2 MPI tasks and n=20, how would you do that?

Comment: Even for learning MPI that's a poor example to work with.  For one, even a single thread or process will rip through every natural number it can represent at a very high rate; it wouldn't surprise me if the cost of communications between MPI processes outweighed any benefit from decomposing the problem.  For two, there is a closed form solution to the problem which will be several orders of magnitude faster still ...

Comment: The domain decomposition so to speak does not require much data transfer, and then only a generally well tuned collective is needed at the end, so MPI might be faster for large n. But yes, MPI does not outperform maths here!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to approach this problem.

About Input:

Once you get your value of terms from rank 0, say it is `N`. You have to broadcast this value among all the processes.

About Parallelising:

Say you have `M` MPI processes (ranks) and total `N` terms.

`rank 0` should calculate the sum of natural numbers from `0` to `N/M - 1`

`rank 1` should calculate the sum of natural numbers from `N/M` to `2*N/M - 1`

`rank 2` should calculate the sum of natural numbers from `2*N/M` to `3*N/M -1`

..

`rank M` should calculate the sum of natural numbers from (M-1)*N/M to `M*N/M - 1`

So in principle, each rank should calculate the sum of natural numbers between the range `rank*N/M` + `(rank+1)*N/M - 1`. So change your for loop to accommodate this information. *Assumption: N is divisible by M. If not take the remainder numbers and give it to thelast rank*.

After that, Use `MPI_Reduce` to find the total sum and store the result in rank 0.

This is very naive approach and can use to learn the very basics of domain decomposition, work distribution etc.